# What can I assert in this method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have absolutely no idea what I can `assert` or `verify` in this method.  I have two tests written so far which provide 100% coverage, one hits the break and another `throws` `HttpClientErrorException` which is caught by the `catch`.  Any ideas much appreciated, I'm currently looking into ways of verifying my log statements but not sure if this is the correct approach..

```
public void putDataSomewhere(Doc doc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = aUtil.create3RestTemplate(props);
                restTemplate.postForEntity(props.getUrl(), doc.toJSONString(), String.class);
                log.info("Document [{}] successfully uploaded to Archive", doc.getKey());
                break;
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
                log.error("Attempt [{}] failed to send document properties [{}] to Archive", i+1, doc.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not verify some log statements. They can change in subtle ways and then your tests fail. You should rather verify, if `postForEntity` has been called exaclty three times. Provided, you mock `restTemplate`. As for the `catch` case, it would make sense to rethrow a custom exception and test if that has been thrown in the end

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at the existing code to decide what to test. Instead, try thinking about the requirements you want your piece of code to satisfy, and then check that you have a test for each requirement. If you've specified all your requirements, then there's no reason to continue looking for test cases to write. Testing your log messages won't provide very much value, and will cost a fair bit to maintain.

Comment: I ended up verifying how many times `restTemplate.postForEntity` is called.  3 for the thrown exception and 1 for the successful run.  Pretty much covers everything I need.